# Matrix Inversion of $f(X) = (X^{-1}-A)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

We have a function
$$
f(X) = X^{-1} - A, 
$$
and I have to show with the help of Newtons's method:
$$
X_{k+1} = X_k - Df(X_k)^{-1}f(X_k)
$$
that the iteration takes the following form for $f(X_k)$:
$$
X_{k+1} = X_k + X_k(I-AX_k).
$$
I tried to solve it with:
$$
Df(X_k)^{-1}f(X_k) = -f^{-1}(X_k)f(X_k)f^{-1}(X_k),
$$
but didn't succeed. Note: $f$ is defined in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$

Comment: What is $D$? I assume it's the Hessian of $f(X_k)$ w.r.t. $X_k$? 
Also you are trying to solve the equation $f(X)=0$?

Comment: @BinxuWang王彬旭 It is the gradient.

Comment: So $D$ operates on the function $f(X)$ or operates on the inverse of it $D(f(X)^{-1})$ I think it's the latter?

Comment: Are you sure that it is $X_{k+1} = X_k + X_k(I-AX_k)$ and not $X_{k+1} = X_k + X_k(I-X_kA)$?

Comment: The notation is a little bit fuzzy in the equation $Df(X_k)^{-1}f(X_k)$. I think the $-1$ means matrix inverse of the output of $f(X)$ instead of the inverse function $f^{-1}$ applied to $X$ right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could approach this problem using *differentials*
$$\eqalign{
\def\X{X^{-1}}
F &= \X - A \\
dF &= -\X\;dX\;\X \\
}$$
Since you want the updated value of the function $F_+$
to equal **zero**
$$dF = \Big(F_+-F\Big) = -F$$
Substitute into the differential expression and solve
$$\eqalign{
-F &= -\X\,dX\;\X \\
dX &= XFX \\
(X_+-X) &= X\Big(\X-A\Big)X \\
X_+ &= X \;+\; \Big(X\X X-XAX\Big) \\
X_+ &= X \;+\; X\Big(I-AX\Big) \\
}$$
which has the desired form.

---

NB: For ease of typing, I use a streamlined notation which suppresses the iteration counter, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
X_+ = X_{k+1},\qquad X = X_k,\qquad dX=dX_k=\big(X_{k+1}-X_k\big) \\
}$$
The initial matrix $X_0$ is very important for this iteration to converge. The following should work
$$X_0 = \frac{A^T}{\|A\|^2_F}$$